# Uploading file from android to wcf service

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, file-upload

I am getting problem at wcf end while i am sending a doc file from android to wcf service. Problem is that while open the uploaded file at wcf end, the content of doc file is some unreadable text. Below is the code:
**wcf code**

```
FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("D:\\myfile.doc", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
    bytesRead = mystream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead > 0);

    fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    fileToupload.Close();
    fileToupload.Dispose();
    return "success";
```

and **android code**

```
 package com.example.filedemo;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import android.os.Environment;

public class HttpUpload {

    public static int res ;

    public void myUploadedfile(){


        try {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
            HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://10.160.0.18:85/Service.svc/UploadImage?fn=abc.doc");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("fileContents", new FileBody(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"abc.doc")));


            httpost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            System.out.println("Response : "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            res = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

}
```

Please reply soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your `WCF` does not seem correct, try the below modification:

```
FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("D:\\myfile.doc", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

while((bytesRead = mystream.Read(bytearray)) > 0) 
{    
  fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead); // Write directly to the file
  totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
} 


fileToupload.Close();
fileToupload.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your kind help....It works fine when i upload doc, xls etc...but can you tell me what if i am going to upload a video or audio file..????Size will be unlimited or else upto 3 to 4 GB?

Comment: It should be the same but you will need to use larger buffer size and support sort of `upload resume` in case of connection failure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still problem is there when i uploaded video file its uploaded but its not opening, i try to open with all player such as media player, vlc player etc but its not opening. waiting for reply..... thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that the file size in the server is exactly as the uploaded file, and start testing by a small audio/video files first

Comment: ya i tried with only 6mb which is running in tablet but when we uploaded it then the size of video file same at server end  but its not running. can you u help by sample code which working successfully